# Can I set the value of "it" in my Rspec tests?

Tags: ruby, validation, rspec

In some Rspec model specs, we have several tests like this:

```
it { should have_many(:labels) }
```

Unfortunately, we also have a hook that runs before validation which causes an error when the object hasn't been set up.

Is it possible for me to set the value of "it" for these tests? I want to give it a properly initialized object so that my pre-validation hooks don't cause problems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this?

```
describe "#validations" do
    subject { Factory.build :some_model }
    it { should have_many(:labels) }
end
```

Comment: Yep! Exactly that. I just couldn't remember the name of that method. Documentation here: https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-0/docs/subject/explicit-subject

Comment: Thanks for the help. "It" makes a lousy search term. :)